# How to bind Image source with view model property WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, imagesource

I have found a word cloud NuGet package after messing around in a test app I manage to get the world cloud to work, but I was using imgWordcloud.Source = bi. When trying to use a property binding the image does not appear in the view but whilst stepping through the program the bitmap image exists in the property WordcloudImage.

C# Code:

```
private ImageSource _wordcloudImage;
public ImageSource WordcloudImage
{
    get { return _wordcloudImage; }
    set
    {
        if (_wordcloudImage != value)
        {
            _wordcloudImage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WordcloudImage");
        }
    }
}
```

More C# Code:

```
public void CreateWordcloud()
{
    List<string> Data = new List<string>();

    List<int> Data2 = new List<int>();

    WordCloud.WordCloud wc = new WordCloud.WordCloud(200, 200, false, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(100, 168, 58, 117), 40, 1);

    foreach (var item in WordcloudExportItems[0].snapshots[0].items.items)
    {
        Data.Add(item.title);
        Data2.Add(2);
    }

    // ImageSource ...
    System.Drawing.Image imgWinForms = wc.Draw(Data, Data2);
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    // Save to a memory stream...
    imgWinForms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    // Rewind the stream...
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Tell the WPF image to use this stream...
    bi.StreamSource = ms;

    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    bi.EndInit();

    _wordcloudImage = bi;
}
```

WPF:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="lvWordcloudExport" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding WordcloudExportItems}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWordcloudExport, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisibleWordcloudExport, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter} }"
    >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Wordcloud" Header="Data"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="whhiofw"></TextBlock>
                            <Image 
                                Name="imgWordcloud" 
                                Source="{Binding WordcloudImage}" 
                                Height="400" 
                                Width="200"
                                />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Set the property, not its backing field, i.e. `WordcloudImage = bi` instead of `_wordcloudImage = bi`. Otherwise no change notification is fired.

Comment: I have done what you said but I also had to take the image from the listview temple to be on its own. It does not show within the datatemplate.

Comment: WordcloudImage is supposed to be a property of the element class of the WordcloudExportItems collection. If that's not the case, your Binding should look differently.

Comment: How do I go about binding it differently because  WordcloudExportItems comes from a class that I used to parse(deserialize) JSON data.